# GroupBy pandas DataFrame and fill/update with most frequent values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to get the most frequent values in a pandas dataframe and fill/update the data with the most frequent value.

**Sample Data**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test_input = pd.DataFrame(columns=[ 'key',          'value'],
                          data=  [[ 1,              'A'    ],
                                  [ 1,              'B'    ],
                                  [ 1,              'B'    ],
                                  [ 1,              np.nan ],
                                  [ 2,              np.nan ],
                                  [ 3,              'C'    ],
                                  [ 3,              np.nan ],
                                  [ 3,              'D'    ],
                                  [ 3,              'D'    ]])
```

```
    key value
0   1   A
1   1   B
2   1   B
3   1   NaN
4   2   NaN
5   3   C
6   3   NaN
7   3   D
8   3   D
```

get most frequent values based on keys

```
def mode(df, key_cols, value_col, count_col):

    return (df.groupby(key_cols + [value_col]).size()
             .to_frame(count_col).reset_index()
             .sort_values(count_col, ascending=False)
             .drop_duplicates(subset=key_cols))
```

```
freq_df = mode(test_input, ['key'], 'value', 'count')

    key value   count
1   1   B   2
3   3   D   2
```

How can I fill the most frequent values on the original `dataframe`

**Desired Output**

```
    key value
0   1   B
1   1   B
2   1   B
3   1   B
4   2   NaN
5   3   D
6   3   D
7   3   D
8   3   D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with custom lambda function with [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) and `iter` with `next` trick for `NaN`s if empty `mode` (because missing value(s)):

```
test_input['value'] = (test_input.groupby('key')['value']
                                 .transform(lambda x: next(iter(x.mode()), np.nan)))
print (test_input)
   key value
0    1     B
1    1     B
2    1     B
3    1     B
4    2   NaN
5    3     D
6    3     D
7    3     D
8    3     D
```

Solution with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
test_input['value'] = (test_input.groupby('key')['value']
                           .transform(lambda x: next(iter(x.value_counts().index), np.nan)))
print (test_input)
   key value
0    1     B
1    1     B
2    1     B
3    1     B
4    2   NaN
5    3     D
6    3     D
7    3     D
8    3     D
```